# What's the difference between 'TX' and 'tx' in modsecurity rule

Tags: mod-security

This [page](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#TX) describes definition of 'TX' as following:
"This is the transient transaction collection, which is used to store pieces of data, create a transaction anomaly score, and so on. The variables placed into this collection are available only until the transaction is complete."

In modsecurity we also can frequently see another collection, 'tx', such as following rule:

SecRule

```
REQUEST_COOKIES|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/_pk_ref/|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/* "\bonmouseup\b\W*?\=" \
    "phase:2, rev:'2', ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9', maturity:'8', accuracy:'8', capture, t:none, t:htmlEntityDecode, t:compressWhiteSpace, t:lowercase, ctl:auditLogParts=+E, block, msg:'Cross-site Scripting (XSS) Attack', id:'958418', tag:'OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS', tag:'WASCTC/WASC-8', tag:'WASCTC/WASC-22', tag:'OWASP_TOP_10/A2', tag:'OWASP_AppSensor/IE1', tag:'PCI/6.5.1', logdata:'Matched Data: %{TX.0} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}: %{MATCHED_VAR}', severity:'2', setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}', setvar:tx.xss_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score}, setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score}, setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS-%{matched_var_name}=%{tx.0}"
```

Why are there two similar collections used? Why no just using 'TX'?

Comment: Have you looked this up? The ModSecurity documentation appears to equate TX and tx: http://blog.modsecurity.org/2007/12/using-transacti.html

Comment: From below comment in modsecurity source code, tx is a special case for TX. But I do not understand it.

/* Locate the collection. */
    if (strcasecmp(col_name, "tx") == 0) { /* Special case for TX variables. */
        target_col = msr->tx_vars;
    }

Answer (score 1):

tx and TX are the same collections, without case sensitive, in my view it is a writing pattern when a conditional argument of the rule is uppercase, when the assignment is made in lowercase.